# How to handle a user who is pestering me to answer all of their questions?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, users, specific-user

I am in a situation that I am not sure how to handle. A few days ago I answered a few questions that were by a user, now whenever they post a question they comment on one of my other answers asking me to help them with their new question.

> Hi, @user12345. I understand that your question is important, however, please do not comment on my other answers trying to get assistance with your new question. I am sure that your question will be answered, but I am afraid I will not be able to assist you. Good luck.

I have asked the user to stop to no avail, and have reported their comments as spam. I’ve tried ignoring them for a few days but it is still 4-5 comments a day. It should also be noted that this user is not new, they have been on the site for a year, and has over 100 reputation.

How should I handle this? Is there anything I can do to block this user, or is there something else that I should say to them?

Comment: Mod flag one of their comments and explain what they are doing.

Comment: @Yatin thank you I just reported the latest one, which took place a few minutes ago while posting this question.

Comment: Sorry, I declined your flag by accident while trying to delete it. Comment flags don't count against you, thankfully.

Comment: @BoltClock should I raise it again?

Comment: No need, I can still access it, and re-raising comment flags serves no benefit.

Comment: Ignore them? ...

Comment: @RobertHarvey they are leaving comments on posts directing users to other posts that have nothing to do with the current post. At best, it is creating unnecessary garbage on several unrelated posts, or, at worse, it is hindering and confusing other users. It is best to put a stop to this behavior.

Comment: This is that wackier side of Stack Overflow success and why I am of the opinion that you should keep you SO account detached from your person, so don't intertwine it with social media accounts or github and such (and why I find it strange that [SO invites you to do so](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406660/424903)...). If such clingy people manage to follow you outside of the protective boundaries of this site you can't flag them away anymore.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pestering users to answer one's questions is not allowed on Stack Overflow. You took the correct action by leaving the comment that you did. It's a clear, polite, and firm request to stop asking you for help. If that comment didn't resolve the problem, then there's nothing more you can (or should) do as a regular user. In particular, I'd suggest not engaging with the user in comments any further.

Fortunately, your problem can be solved by users who know how, i.e. diamond moderators. Simply raise a custom moderator flag* and explain clearly, and in as much detail as possible, the situation that you're facing. Include links to multiple comments from the user, so that it's clear that there's a pattern. You could also explain that you already asked the user to stop, and that it didn't work. Moderators will get in touch with the user, and explain to them that their behavior is inappropriate.

I would give it a bit of time for your flag to be handled. It's likely that the user will stop pestering you after that point, but if they don't, you should raise another flag, and mention that you already raised a flag previously. Moderators may then take more drastic measures as they deem necessary in order for the user to stop.

*Make sure to raise the flag on a post instead of on a comment. Comment flags can get resolved by accident without a moderator actually reviewing it. Also, character limits on comment flags are much lower than for post flags, and in situations like this, you will probably want to use the additional space they afford.

Comment: Might be worth recommending to raise the flag _on a post_ whenever we want the moderator to do more than just delete a comment, so that the flag is not resolved by accident.

Comment: and custom comment flags have limited length (150 chars IIRC) as opposed to custom post flags allowing for a whopping 500 chars ...

Comment: I think that is a good idea. I just basically said help with a link to this post. Before I ran out of space